# Incoming E-mail intercepted by PYTHON's ( sys.stdin.read(1024) ) is missing title and body content

Tags: python, sendmail, mod-wsgi, stdin, wsgi

I use `/etc/aliases` to redirect incoming emails
for the username `"ooo"` to a python script

( handled by `SENDMAIL` )

```
ooo:    "|/usr/bin/python /2/a.wsgi"
```

this is what `a.wsgi` looks like.

```
import os
import sys

a = sys.stdin.read(1024)
f = open('/2/email.txt','w')
f.write(a)
```

I sent a test e-mail to myself from my yahoo e-mail account
but the whole title and body is missing.

on purpose i created a long title consisting of lot's of o's
and a body consisting of lot's of o's with multiple lines
so that i could see it.

when i look into the intercepted e-mail by python..
this is what email.txt file looks like.

```
[root@a 2]# cat email.txt
From a*****@ymail.com Thu Jul 25 09:41:49 2013
Received: from nm23-vm1.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com (nm23-vm1.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com [98.139.213.141])
    by domain.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id r6P9fm88005190
    for <ooo@*****.tld>; Thu, 25 Jul 2013 09:41:48 GMT
Received: from [98.139.215.142] by nm23.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Jul 2013 17:26:26 -0000
Received: from [98.139.212.228] by tm13.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Jul 2013 17:26:26 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1037.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Jul 2013 17:26:26 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 45121.53358.bm@omp1037.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 29958 invoked by uid 60001); 25 Jul 2013 17:26:26 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=ymail.com; s=s1024; t=1374773185; bh=Nc9zHE1K2q237s4A2qN53+4bWmq6BswfttyIcwmUsF8=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=tN89b5lX46otPfK9builCXVNLty3jVx[root@a 2]#
```

as you can see the subject is empty and body is not visible either.

otherwise i e-mailed myself

Subject: oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
Body : also lot's of o's but multiple lines so it'd be easy to see.

Comment: why would you delete the question?  This way, others with the same problem cannot benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = sys.stdin.read(1024)
```

reads no more than 1024 bytes. That is roughly the length of the email.txt you've posted. The discrepancy is probably due to redactions.

So, if you want the entire message, use

```
a = sys.stdin.read()
```